# How to customize layouts in Goldberg CMS?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, content-management-system, ruby-on-rails-plugins

I maintain legacy website running on Ruby on Rails and Goldberg CMS. Some things that are really trivial to do in Rails are difficult to implement in Goldberg. For instance: I want some content pages created by Goldberg CMS to use non-standard layout (currently, every Goldberg page uses default application.html.erb layout) - how can I do that? As far as I can tell, I can't configure it in CMS UI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you take a quick look at how the layout is defined in the application's code :
[lib/goldberg/controller.rb](http://github.com/urbanus/goldberg/blob/master/lib/goldberg/controller.rb)

You'll see the following line :

```
base.layout "application"
```

The layout is hard coded in the application. So if you want to define an other layout for it, I'm afraid you will have to patch Goldberg.

Comment: Thanks. So there's no easy way. I'll try to work around it (or patch Goldberg), so far we use just one template with lots of IF conditions :), which is kinda lame.